# Unity Question: How Can I Switch From One prefab To Another With GetAxis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to bind the up and down arrow keys to cycle through different sprites upon being pressed. If one end is reached, it would loop back to the first sprite. I've tried using the following code:

```
public class PhaseChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // saved for efficiency
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject prefabMoon0;
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject prefabMoon1;
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject prefabMoon2;
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject prefabMoon3;
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject prefabMoon4;

    // needed for new phase
    GameObject currentPhase;

    bool previousFramePhaseChangeInput = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Start is called before the first frame update
    /// </summary>
    void Start()
    {
        currentPhase = Instantiate<GameObject>(prefabMoon0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update is called once per frame
    /// </summary>
    void Update()
    {
        // change phase on up arrow or down arrow
        if (Input.GetAxis("ChangePhase") > 0)
        {
            // only change phase on first input frame
            if (!previousFramePhaseChangeInput)
            {
                previousFramePhaseChangeInput = true;

                // Save current position and destroy current phase
                Destroy(currentPhase);

                // instantiate next phase
                if (currentPhase = prefabMoon0)
                {
                    currentPhase = Instantiate(prefabMoon1);
                }
                else if (currentPhase = prefabMoon1)
                {
                    currentPhase = Instantiate(prefabMoon2);
                }
                else if (currentPhase = prefabMoon2)
                {
                    currentPhase = Instantiate(prefabMoon3);
                }
                else if (currentPhase = prefabMoon3)
                {
                    currentPhase = Instantiate(prefabMoon4); 
            else
            {
                // no phase change input
                previousFramePhaseChangeInput = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I attach the script to my main camera and run it, I'm able to make a single change with the up arrow, and then nothing else happens on subsequent presses.

I feel like I'm really close to making this work, but I also may being doing the whole thing inefficiently. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Also: I know I said sprites in my post and am sharing a script that calls on prefabs. I didn't know how to approach this using just the sprites without making a prefab for each. Is it possible to do this without separate prefabs for each sprite?

Comment: Seems like you are assigning in your if statements instead of comparing references. Have you tried rectifying it? Moreover, have you ever tried your hands on [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: I've used foreach arrays before, but I'm not sure if that's what I would need here. Could you please explain a bit further how this applies? I'm also unsure of what you mean by "rectifying it." Thanks.

Comment: The `if-statements` has `if (currentPhase = prefabMoon0)`, whereas it should be `if (currentPhase == prefabMoon0)` with `==` instead of `=`.  Instead of using `if-elseif` you can simply iterate over each index and increment its value when needed something like `++index; index %= prefabArray.Length` and use this `index` value to assign a new prefab or use [object pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am reading up on object pooling. I do apologize, but I'm very new to scripting and to Unity; would you be able to walk me through the solution you suggested above? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Simply first of all replace each `if (currentPhase = prefabMoon0)/if (currentPhase = prefabMoon1)/if (currentPhase = prefabMoon2)...` with `if (currentPhase == prefabMoon0)/if (currentPhase == prefabMoon1)/if (currentPhase == prefabMoon2)...` and check if that solves the issue you are facing.

Comment: @nIcEcOw That is one issue but won't be enough (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68888248/7111561)) ;)

Comment: @labmate: Please don't apologize as you did nothing wrong. I am just trying to point you to areas you might need to improve on. Everything will come at it's own pace, KEEP UP THE GOOD WORK and KEEP LEARNING :-) Kindly do let us know, in case something is not clear still, will try to change the approach to explain a bit better. For the REST, YOU're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Problems

- First of all you are using assignments

  ```
  currentPhase = XY
  ```

  where you should be using

  ```
  currentPhase == XY
  ```

  The reason why it still compiles is the implicit conversion operator for [`UnityEngine.Object` -> `bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html). Basically your assigning equals writing

  ```
  currentPhase = XY;
  if(currentPhase)
  ```
- It won't work like this either way because you are using `Instantiate` to create a **new clone** of a prefab which will of course have a different **reference** than the original prefab it was cloned from.

  So even if your checks where looking like

  ```
  if(currentPhase == XY)
  ```

  they will ever be `true`.

#### Solution

Instead of checking for reference equality I would rather store all prefabs/instances in an **array**

```
public GameObject[] phases;
```

and then simply have an `int` **index** for this array so you can simply move to the next element from the array by increasing the index.

```
private int currentPhase;
```

And you can increase it and make it wrap around using e.g.

```
currentPhase = (currentPhase + 1) % phases.Length;
```

so it will always grow from `0` up to `phases.Length - 1` and then start over from `0` again.

And then I don't know the exact requirements of your use case but I would suggest to rather not all the time use `Instantiate` and `Destroy` but rather have already all the objects as instances under your object and just **(de)actívate** them!

you could do this like e.g.

```
public GameObject[] phases;
private int currentPhase;

private void Awake ()
{
    Init();
}

private void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("ChangePhase") > 0)
    {
        if (!previousFramePhaseChangeInput)
        {
            previousFramePhaseChangeInput = true;

            NextPhase();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        previousFramePhaseChangeInput = false;
    }
}

// Disables all phases except the first one and sets the current index to 0
private void Init()
{
    for(var i = 1; i < phases.Length; i++)
    {
        phases[i].SetActive(false);
    }

    phases[0].SetActive(true);
    currentPhase = 0;
}

// Disables the current phase and enables the next one
// wraps around at the end of the array
public void NextPhase()
{
    phases[currentPhase].SetActive(false);

    // increase the counter and wrap around at the end of the array
    currentPhase = (currentPhase + 1) % phases.Length;

    phases[currentPhase].SetActive(true);
}
```

---

If you still want to `Instantiate` the objects because having them already in the scene is no option (for whatever reason) you could do it right before calling `Init` like e.g.

```
public GameObject[] phasePrefabs;

private GameObject[] phases;

private void Awake ()
{
    var amount = phasePrefabs.Length;
    phases = new GameObject [amount];

    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        phases[i] = Instantiate(phasePrefabs[i]);
    }

    Init();
}
```

Though as said I would prefer to already have them right away as this is way less error prone ;)

Comment: Really nice explanation +1 for that :-)